# how to detect if a field has input in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I was trying to create a validation in laravel controller, where if one of the fields has input, then it will validate the rest of the fields to be `'required'`. But it prompts `Error
Class 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input' not found`. Please help

```
         if(Input::has('quantity1') || has('unit1') || has('dimension1') || has('price1')){
            $data = $request->validate([
                    'quantity1' => 'required',
                    'unit1' => 'required',
                    'dimension1' => 'required',
                    'price1' => 'required',
                ]);
```

Comment: what's your laravel version

Comment: 'aliases' => [    
        'Input' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::class,
    ],

Comment: you can use `$request->quantity1` rather than `Input::has('quantity1')`

Comment: its version 6 @TsaiKoga

Answer (score 0):

Use `required_with` laravel validation rule...

```
$data = $request->validate([
                    'quantity1' => 'required_with:unit1,dimension1,price1',
                    'unit1' => 'required_with:quantity1,dimension1,price1',
                    'dimension1' => 'required_with:quantity1,unit1,price1',
                    'price1' => 'required_with:quantity1,unit1,dimension1',
                ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Input` is deprecated.

I would highly suggest creating a custom request class and using that.

The benfits include:

1. Conforming to SOLID principles.
2. Easy place to manage your rules and messages.
3. Easy place to handle permissions should you choose.
4. Can be extended and reused as needed.

--

Here are the steps how to do that:

1. Run `php artisan make:request YourCustomRequestClassNamae`
2. Fill the new `app\Http\Requests\YourCustomRequestClassNamae.php` file with:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class YourCustomRequestClassNamae extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'quantity1'     => 'required',
            'unit1'         => 'required',
            'dimension1'    => 'required',
            'price1'        => 'required',
        ];
    }
}
```

3. In the controller do something like:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

...

use App\Http\Requests\YourCustomRequestClassNamae;

...

class YourControllerName extends Controller
{

...

    public function yourMethodName(YourCustomRequestClassNamae $request)
    {
        $validatedData = $request->validated();

...
```

If the validation above fails it will return back with a 422 and the messages automatically ready to be pulled from the message bag.

Sources:

- https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#form-request-validation

Example in the wild:

- https://github.com/jeremykenedy/larablog/blob/master/app/Http/Requests/StoreTagRequest.php
- https://github.com/jeremykenedy/larablog/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/Admin/TagController.php#L7
- https://github.com/jeremykenedy/larablog/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/Admin/TagController.php#L56